# How can I link my HTML form to an Excel Spreadsheet?

Tags: html, css, excel

I am working on a website in HTML5 and CSS3 and I'm wondering if there is any way to take the user's answers and export them into a Microsoft Excel Spreadsheet. I have already tried using a VBScript, but I would prefer another way, seeing as VBScript doesn't work in most modern-day browsers. I would like an external file because I want this form on the bottom of multiple pages. Lol don't mind what the site is being made on.

```css
nav {   background-color: #65bbe9;
        margin-top: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        border: 3px solid #000000;
}

#wrapper {  margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 80%;
            min-width: 960px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000033;
            -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000033;
            box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000033;
            font-family: 'Akzidenz-Grotesk'
}
#content {  border: 3px solid #000033;
            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-right: 10px
}
body {  background-color: #aceaff;
}
footer {    font-style: italic;
            font-family: 'Rabiohead';
            font-size: 125%
}
@font-face {    font-family: 'Rabiohead';
                src: url('rabiohead.ttf');
}
@font-face {    font-family: 'Akzidenz-Grotesk';
                src: url('Akzidenz-Grotesk.ttf');
}
h2 {    font-family: 'Rabiohead';
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 40px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>Dear Evan Hansen - The Animated Film</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href="hansen.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <nav>
                <img src="logo.gif" height="100" width="155.56">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="homeselection.gif" height="100" width="155.56"></a>
                <a href="what.html"><img src="what.gif" height="100" width="155.56"></a>
                <a href="cast.html"><img src="cast.gif" height="100" width="155.56"></a>
                <a href="release.html"><img src="release.gif" height="100" width="155.56"></a>
                <a href="work.html"><img src="work.gif" height="100" width="155.56"></a>
            </nav>
            <div id="content">
                <h2>Dear Evan Hansen: The Animated Film</h2>
                <p>
                    The broadway musical "<i>Dear Evan Hansen</i>" is being brought to your screen! When our cast read the novel
                    created after the musical was released, they fell in love with this powerful story. This animation is not released yet, and
                    does not have any connections to <i>Universal Studios</i>, who currently have rights to the creation of a "<i>Dear Evan Hansen</i>"
                    movie. If you're excited, head to our YouTube channel linked below and consider subscribing, so when an official trailer is released,
                    you will be one of the first ones to know about it, or fill out the newsletter form to add your name to our email list.
                </p>
                <br>
                <br>
                <h2>Join Our Newsletter!</h2>
                <form method="get">
                    <br>
                    Email: <input type="email" name="email" id="email"> &nbsp; <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
                </form>
                <br>
                <br>
                <footer>
                    Copyright &copy; Alex Gutowski
                    <br>
                    <a href="mailto:alexgutowski@gmail.com">alexgutowski@gmail.com</a>
                    <br>
                    All Rights Reserved
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance!

Alex Gutowski

Comment: You're gonna need much more than just html and css to achieve this. Maybe you can use Google Sheets, check out this article: https://medium.com/@dmccoy/how-to-submit-an-html-form-to-google-sheets-without-google-forms-b833952cc175

Comment: Alternatively, your form can add the submission as a comma delimited row to a text file that serves as your submission log.  Then you could always download/import the CSV into Excel.  Bear in mind, you'll want to consider any privacy/Personal Information concerns for your form data.

Comment: And a third option: create/manage the signup for our mailing list form with a third party service such as MailChimp or ConstantContact.  They'll offer better spam protection and common services needed for email marketing.

Comment: You will need some kind of server side back end for this.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a third-party tool.

first you can save the form details on your server.

then you use a vba script to retrieve the form data from the server.